# List items don't align properly when using a variable pitch font in Org mode

Tags: faces, fonts, variable-pitch

I'm using the "Charis SIL Compact" font for Org mode and everything looks fine except the second, third lines of list items that span multiple lines don't align properly.

[image]

When using a variable pitch font some elements don't align properly such as code blocks, tables, etc.. I have these rules applied:

```
(use-package org-faces
    :ensure nil
    :custom-face
    (org-table ((nil (:inherit fixed-pitch))))
    (org-block ((nil (:inherit fixed-pitch :foreground nil))))
    (org-code  ((nil (:inherit (shadow fixed-pitch)))))  
    (org-indent ((nil (:inherit (org-hide fixed-pitch)))))
    (org-special-keyword ((nil (:inherit (font-lock-comment-face fixed-pitch))))))
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Are you using org-superstar (for example via Doom)? Or how do you get the UTF bullets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-most spaces should all have face `org-indent` assigned already (this is the default face of the wrap- and line-prefix text properties set by `org-indent-mode`). So the only way the misalignment can arise is if the width of the bullet or the space after it are of a different width than a space of font org-indent.

When I call `C-u M-x what-cursor-position` (or `C-u C-x =`) at the space after a bullet, the face is already `org-indent`, while doing the same at a bullet reveals its face is `org-list-dt`. Setting this face to inherit fixed-pitch like you do for org-indent should solve the alignment issue:

```lisp
(use-feature org-faces
    :ensure nil
    :custom-face
    (org-table ((nil (:inherit fixed-pitch))))
    (org-block ((nil (:inherit fixed-pitch :foreground nil))))
    (org-code  ((nil (:inherit (shadow fixed-pitch)))))  
    (org-indent ((nil (:inherit (org-hide fixed-pitch)))))
    (org-special-keyword ((nil (:inherit (font-lock-comment-face fixed-pitch)))))
    (org-list-dt ((nil (:inherit fixed-pitch)))))
```

If this doesn't help, ensure that the UTF character used for the bullet isn't wider than a default fixed-pitch character. This can for example be done by evaluating `(> (string-pixel-width "•") (frame-char-width))` in the scratch buffer with "•" replaced by whatever character you use for the bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they don’t. The spaces at the beginning of the line are not the same width as the other characters. Since each character from a variable width font has a different width, there’s no way that they could ever line up.

Comment: Here's a website https://zzamboni.org/post/beautifying-org-mode-in-emacs/ as you can see in this image https://zzamboni.org/post/beautifying-org-mode-in-emacs/images/emacs-narrow-window.png they can line up

Comment: The problem only happens when `org-indent-mode` is enabled.

Comment: Here you say it's `org-indent-mode` that's causing it. In your question, you say the opposite. Which is it? Please fix the question if necessary.

Comment: The only way the variable-width font can be a problem here is if the width of the bullet and the space after it are of a different width than a space of font org-indent. So one solution would be to assign face org-indent (which is fixed-pitch) to these two characters.